# Does the Concatenation Layer produce really a 4D output in caffe?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, concatenation

I read the documentation about the concatination layer here: [Layer Catalogue Concat](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers/concat.html). It states:

> input:
>
> `n_i * c_i * h * w for each input blob i from 1 to K.`
>
> Output:
>
> if axis = 0: `(n_1 + n_2 + ... + n_K) * c_1 * h * w`, and all input c_i
>   should be the same.
>
> if axis = 1: `n_1 * (c_1 + c_2 + ... + c_K) * h * w`, and all input n_i should be the same.

However, I am having a hard time imagine this, like how can there be a 4 dimensional output, when all layers accept 3D input? Is there some kind of trick to read the 4D output as a 3D output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually input and output have all 4D: batch dimension, number of channels, height and width. You can obtain a different number of dimensions in special cases (e.g. 5D for RGB-D input), but for standard RGB images, 4D is kept everywhere (except for fully connected layers).

Comment: The documentation of caffe always abandons the Batch size before hand. So this is not relating to the batch sizes in general.

Comment: What I meant is that every layer of caffe processes 4D input and outputs usually. Even if the operations are on 3D blocks, they are repeated along the batch size (axis 0). But what do you mean by saying "4D output if input are 3D"? I could have misunderstood your point.

Comment: Well the question could be broken down to "what is the n" in the presented formula?

Comment: So, "n" is the chosen batch_size. The concat layer is able to modify it, since you are free to concatenate stuff along the batch dimension.